# Error: Cannot find module '../../package.json' when i run npm in command-line (even npm -v throughs error)

Tags: node.js, npm

I have seen many questions which might seem similar to this one but i am unable to run anything with npm even `npm -v` throughs error:

```
C:\Users\Aloha>npm -v
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../../package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Aloha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\es6\validate-engines.js
- C:\Users\Aloha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\Aloha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aloha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\es6\validate-engines.js:8:49)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Aloha\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\es6\\validate-engines.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Aloha\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Aloha\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v20.11.1
```

I uninstalled and reinstalled the node to latest version but npm still throughs error.
Tried many solutions but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that **package.json** is missing. Try running

```
npm init
```

which should create the package.json file for you and then run `npm -v`

[image]

Comment: I was unable to use npm command (it said package.json file is missing). I have reinstalled twice and now its working BTW

Comment: @Kiteretsu Have you tried running `npm init`?

Comment: yes. the issue started when i was updating npm using npm i -g npm@latest and i interrupted it before completion. after that nothing related to npm worked on my whole pc